# Can't compile my simple fortran helloworld code

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran95, g95

I'm completely new to fortran, and have only done some python and c++ before. I tried following a tutorial, but couldn't get my compiler to work.

When I try the program:

```
program helloworld
    print *,"Hello World!"
end program helloworld
```

saved as "fort.f" in notepad, using the g95 compiler for windows and then trying both

```
g95 -c fort.f
```

and

```
g95 fort.f -o fort
```

in the correct folder in cmd

I get this:

```
In file fort.f:1

program helloworld
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
In file fort.f:1

program helloworld
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
In file fort.f:3

end program helloworld
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
In file fort.f:3

end program helloworld
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
Error: Unexpected end of file in 'fort.f'
```

I have tried googling the errors, but don't see how they apply to this simple code, that is taken from a tutorial and thus should work. Probably something about my compiling command or installation of g95 then?

Comment: Have you tried putting the file extension '.f90' or '.f95' instead of '.f'? It seems to be parsing it as though it is an older version of FORTRAN.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I did try f95 and f90 on a different code earlier, but I guess then the code was faulty.